# Бот для steam на node.js (не могу найти generateAuthCode)

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, бот, steam-web-api

Приветствую всех.

Пытаюсь написать `бота` для `steam`  и застрял на авторизации,
использую эту [библиотеку](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-totp/blob/master/README.md) для получения кода подтверждения авторизации, но никак не могу понять, где мне взять **значение** которое передается в этот **метод**:

```
var code = SteamTotp.generateAuthCode('cnOgv/KdpLoP6Nbh0GMkXkPXALQ=');
```

Вот пример моего полного кода:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var Steam = require('steam');
var SteamWebLogOn = require('steam-weblogon');
var SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');


var logOnOptions;

var steamClient;
var steamUser;
var steamWebLogOn;
var authCode = '';
var SteamConf = require('steamcommunity-mobile-confirmations');
var steamConf;

var shared_secret = '****************************';

var code = SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(shared_secret);

function steamBotLogger(log) {
    console.log('SteamBot: ',log);
}

function getSHA1(bytes) {
    var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
    shasum.end(bytes);
    return shasum.read();
}

logOnOptions = {
    account_name: '**********',
    password: '**************'
};
logOnOptions.two_factor_code = code;
authCode = '*****';
    try {
        logOnOptions.sha_sentryfile = getSHA1(fs.readFileSync('sentry'));
    } catch (e) {
    if (authCode !== '') {
        logOnOptions.auth_code = authCode;
    }
}

steamClient = new Steam.SteamClient();
steamUser = new Steam.SteamUser(steamClient);
steamWebLogOn = new SteamWebLogOn(steamClient, steamUser);


steamClient.connect();
steamClient.on('debug', steamBotLogger);
steamClient.on('connected', function () {
    steamBotLogger('connected');
    steamUser.logOn(logOnOptions);
});

steamClient.on('logOnResponse', function (logonResp) {
    steamBotLogger(logonResp);
    if (logonResp.eresult === Steam.EResult.OK) {
        steamBotLogger('Logged in!');
    }
});

steamClient.on('servers', function (servers) {
    fs.writeFile('servers', JSON.stringify(servers));
});

steamUser.on('updateMachineAuth', function (sentry, callback) {
    fs.writeFileSync('sentry', sentry.bytes);
    callback({sha_file: getSHA1(sentry.bytes)});
});
```

консоль:

[image: console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Туда нужно ввести данные с файла подобному `ssfn`, который находится по этому пути:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Файл называется**: Steamguard-`**********`

`*********` - ваш steamid